# Assembler messages: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I was tried to build .so file. The file contains libraries such as tbb,dlib. When i execute my cpp file, exception raised [Assembler messages: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'].

```
vector<tbb::atomic<bool> > face_detections_used(face_detections.size());
    if(face_detections_used[detection_ind].compare_and_swap(true, false) == false)
        {
            // Reinitialise the model
                clm_models[model].Reset();
                clm_models[model].detection_success = false;
          detection_success = CLMTracker::DetectLandmarksInVideo(grayscale_image, depth_image, face_detections[detection_ind], clm_models[model], clm_parameters[model]);

            active_models[model] = true;

            break;
            }
```

I thing exception from that code. Any specific cpp flags required for tbb. Any idea about this, its helpful for me thank you

Comment: Googling on the error message found several similar problems. E.g. this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/673085. They say that addition `-mimplicit-it=thumb` to CXXFLAGS (cmake variane: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS) should help.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much its work for me...

Comment: @Tsyvarev my compiler says that flag is unrecognized. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @dmagree: I am not an expert in compiler features. You may fill another question though.

Comment: @dmagree this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35998110/3154588, says to use ``-Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb`` to pass the option from the compiler through to the assembler.

Answer (score 0):

got same error in tbb bitbake recipe in my yocto build while `bitbake` compiling , added `CXXFLAGS=" -Wa,-mimplicit-thumb"` in *tbb.bb* file helps me. you can try `TARGET_CXXFLAGS=" -Wa,-mimplicit-thumb"` aswell.