# How to use -Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb for " thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block "?

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, tbb, tegra

When building OpenCV with TBB on Jetson TK1, I am hit by the problems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998110/3154588 and [Assembler messages: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696870/assembler-messages-error-thumb-conditional-instruction-should-be-in-it-block).

However, I can't really figure out how to add -Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb to solve the problem. I add it to CMakelists.txt file in OpenCV file, just before CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS,  but it doesn't help.

/tmp/ccDH2kIW.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccDH2kIW.s:715: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'
/tmp/ccDH2kIW.s:1316: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block --`strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'
/tmp/ccDH2kIW.s:5706: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'
/tmp/ccDH2kIW.s:6001: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block --`strexeq r6,r5,[r4]'
/tmp/ccDH2kIW.s:6636: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r3,[r7]'

Comment: "I add it to CMakeLists" - that's not a very accurate description. Create a minimal CMake project (not OpenCV) and learn how to add `-Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb` there. This seems to be yet another "can't isolate sub-problems" question.

Comment: Only in CMakeFile.txt can I find out CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS……

Comment: Really, `-mimplicit-it` is a bandaid.  The TBB template code should add `IT` instructions so that either ARM or THUMB will work.  Looking at the current development releases, this seems to be fixed (`__TBB_machine_xxx()` in gcc_armv7.h in TBB source.  Use tbb-2017 update 5 if possible.