# Why am i getting "thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block" error

Tags: opencv, qt-creator, odroid

I am trying to build an opencv project with QtCreator on ODROID-XU4. But when i try to build the project it throws "thumb conditional" error. 
I tried to follow this 
[Assembler messages: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `strexeq r1,r2,[r4]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696870/assembler-messages-error-thumb-conditional-instruction-should-be-in-it-block)

But it doesn't work for me. Not sure whether its a bug in QtCreator or do i need to setup some compiler directives.

OS - Ubuntu 14.04.1
ODROID-XU4

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on my Jetson TX1 board, try adding this to the Cmake config line :

```
-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Wa,-mimplicit-it=thumb"
```